# Java Applet Image Load

Tags: java, applet, awt, paint, imageicon

I want to display an image icon in my applet.I created a **package resources** and saved my image in it.This is what i tried :-

```
Image logo;//I declare globally
logo = getImage("logo.jpg");//I initialize in the constructor
```

**And i use this proceedure**

```
 public Image getImage(String name){
                URL imgUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/"+name);
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imgUrl);
                return icon.getImage();
            }

 public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
             if (logo!=null){
                    g.drawImage(logo, 30, 30, null);
                }
             g.drawString("Hwllo", 12, 12);
        }
```

Then i call the:

```
repaint() //In the Constructor
```

But i dont see an image or my String.What might be the problem.Moreover is there any easier method to load images in the Applet??

Comment: I think a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is going to be more useful

Comment: The SSCCE helped!! Basically the image was loading but i had a bunch of Panels hiding it

Comment: This is one of the reasons we suggest avoiding overriding `paint` of top level containers (or `paint` generally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You setting the URL to the

```
URL imgUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/"+name);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imgUrl);
```

But while Calling paint method, you are calling the logo variable

```
 g.drawImage(logo, 30, 30, this);
```

The problem is in your setting URL value, set URL to your logo variable like

```
URL url = new URL(/*Your resources herre*/, /*Your file name here*/);
logo=getImage(url);
```

After that display image using paint method.

Comment: That is not the problem.There are several ways to do the same thing.

Comment: You just set valid url to your variable. And then pass it to logo variable. Can you get my point?

Comment: Please change `g.drawImage(logo, 30, 30, null);` to `g.drawImage(logo, 30, 30, this);` so I can up-vote!  `Applet` implements `ImageObserver`, so we can avoid having to use a `MediaTracker`.